# Редактирование кода NetBeans

Tags: javascript, html, netbeans

Есть неприятная проблема с которой я столкнулся, в NetBeans некоторые куски кода а именно те которые заключены `<script id="tmpl_SearchHeader" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl "><script>` не редактируются, все что внутри черным цветом(синтаксис не посвечивается) иногда только срабатывает то что я могу редактировать данные внутри  блока, но все же доставляет большое неудобство. Что делать?

Comment: А что такое `x-jquery-tmpl`? Наверно netbeans не знает его синтаксис вот и не подсвечивает. Раньше netbeans не понимал синтаксис например JSX (помесь javascript с xml), но  добавили поддержку этого ужо-ежа и теперь  понимает и подсвечивает.  А про "не редактируется" верно брехня?

Comment: @Sergey вопрос решился установкой netbeans 8.1, Плагин jQuery Templates – это «движок шаблонов»